# Non-homogeneous solution to the second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the DE of the form:

$$(x+1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}-y = (x+1)^2$$

How can one, without much guess work propose a potential solution to the non-homogeneous part of the equation? And if you have a resource that talks about a smart ways to assume a form of $y$ for the non-homogeneous part of the differential equations like this, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Start by trying $x^2$. The lhs comes out to $x^2+2x+2$. So you want $x^2-1$.

Comment: if we obtain: $x^2+2x+2$, how do you deduce that we need $x^2-1$?

Comment: The equation is linear in $y$. If we put $y=-1$ the lhs just gives $-1$.

Comment: if we put $y=-1$ we get $1$ :) no?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you want $x^2+1$.

Comment: what exactly does linear mean? that the derivatives are not being multiplied by $y$ and $y$ is not multiplied by itself? And if so, then how can we exploit this property in this case. (I am still not entirely sure I understand). sorry

Comment: Yes, that is right. Linear equations are much easier to solve. We first need to get a solution to the inhomogeneous part. Having got that as say $k(x)$, if $y=f(x),g(x)$ are solutions for the homogeneous equation, then  $y=k(x)+Af(x)+Bg(x)$ is a solution to the original equation and we can use $A,B$ to satisfy the initial conditions.

Comment: oh, ok. I was aware of that property. I still fail to see that is $x^2$ produces the result $x^2+2x+2$ then $x^2+1$ should give zero. I mean obviously if I plug it in I will see it, but the problem is in spotting it before actually plugging it in, or I would be plugging tons of constants

Comment: If you put in $y=k$ for a constant $k$, then it does not affect the $y'$ or $y''$ terms, so you know that *some* value of $k$ will fix the constant term.

Comment: Got it. I didn't notice that there was a problem with constant term